# why cant my c++ code show cout string

Tags: c++

this is my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "test.h"

void main()
{
    Solution aa;
    aa.aaa();

    cin.get();
}
```

this is my test.h

```
#pragma once

class Solution {
public:
    void aaa() {};
};
```

this is my test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:  

    void aaa() {
        cout << "aaaaa" << endl;
    };
};
```

and when I run the c++ code, it shows nothing. Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `test.h` declared and defined a `Solution` class, with an `aaa()` class method that does absolutely nothing.

```
 void aaa() {};
```

See, the `aaa()` method does nothing.

Your `main()` called this method, that does absolutely nothing.

End result: nothing happened, as expected.

You also happened to have a `test.cpp` that happened to declare and define its own class, of the same name. At the very least, this is undefined behavior, and I would point my finger and laugh at any C++ compiler+linker that decided that there was nothing wrong with linking together both `main.cpp` and `test.cpp`.

Comment: *"point my finger and laugh at any C++ compiler+linker"* - it'd be interesting to know if any compilers do warn.  Because it's defined inside the class, test.h's version of `Solution::aaa()` is implicitly inline, so there's probably no related symbol in `main.o` to conflict with test.o's.  (FWIW, VC12 - from VS2013 - displays no warning when each .cpp's compile separately then linked, nor when test.obj is compiled first then `cl /EHsc main.cpp test.obj`).

Comment: I found it hard to believe there'd be no error so ran it under VS2013 like Tony D. Sure enough no errors, no warnings. I added `void DefTwice_Test() { Solution dd; dd.aaa(); }` to test.cpp. Still nothing. I appended a call to `DefTwice_Test()` in `main()` - still no error/warning!  Interesting that with incremental linking it displays two blank lines but with full rebuild it displays `aaaaa` twice. This would have to be a result of the order the linker picks up test.obj and main.obj, right?

Answer (score 1):

In test.h:

```
void aaa() {};
```

Notice that you put empty brackets instead of just a semicolon after the (). If you want to write a function declaration you just write the function name and parameters but not the brackets. Now the compiler thinks that you want to write a function that does nothing. (I'm surprised that this didn't cause a linking error)

Answer (score 1):

Your `test.h` and `test.cpp` files are implemented incorrectly. They should look more like this instead:

test.h

```
#pragma once

class Solution {
public:
    void aaa();
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Solution::aaa() {
    cout << "aaaaa" << endl;
}
```